# Is There Alternative to self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false in Swift?

Tags: swift

i Have an Xcode application that is doing some Bakcgorund work.
while it is doing that to block the user from pressing the Login Button again i'm using:

```
self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

The only issue with that is that the user doesn't see anything on screen and may think the application is just stuck.
is thee an alternative that has some visual aid to show the screen is blocked ?
(Without developing such Dialog)

Comment: you can show activity indicator UI for this. Once work is done just remove the activity indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the login button (and any other controls) rather than the entire view:

```
loginButton.isEnabled = false
```

You can style the button's disabled state to your preference if you don't like the default look (which is slightly greyed out).

Answer (score 0):

Block the interaction of your UIButton only.

On Button click:-

```
sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

And on completion of your request, Make it enable:-

```
btnName.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Comment: I would rather disable the button like PGDev and JonJ demonstrated in their answers. This gives the button a chance to reflect its state by a different font color, background, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can set one flag when you start background task and reset it on task complete

```
fileprivate var isLoading:Bool = false


func startBackgroundTask() {
   guard !isLoading else { return } // if task is running just return
   isLoading = true
   // don't forget to reset it on background task complete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UIActivityIndicator` for this kind of requirement.

Add a `UIActivityIndicator` on the `viewController` in `storyboard` and create it's `outlet` in `viewController's` class.

```
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
```

**Once you click the `loginButton`,**

1. Set `self.loginButton.isEnabled = false`
2. Start animating the `activityIndicator` using `activityIndicator.startAnimating()`

**After the background work is done,**

3. Set `self.loginButton.isEnabled = true`
4. Stop animating the `activityIndicator` using `activityIndicator.stopAnimating()`

**Example:**

```
@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isEnabled = false
    self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    //Your background task
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "")!) { (data, response, error) in
        //Callback after the task is finished 
        DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in
            self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            sender.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```